Change AWS Region dynamically
I have several AWS LogGroups registered in my DB, each located in different AWS regions. Can I change the AWS Region at runtime in C# after object created as line below indicates?
var client = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(AwsCredentials, _RegionEndPoint);

The reason behind this is I have One Singleton object in DI Container register for one of my WorkerService built to get all NEW logs events for all LogGroup's streams that runs every 5 minutes. Therefor, I don't need more than one AWS CloudWatch Instance to Loop on all LogGroups and watch the newly inserted events by changing only Region value.
Here the Singleton Object:
       services.AddSingleton(sp =>
        {                
            BasicAWSCredentials AwsCredentials;
            RegionEndpoint _RegionEndPoint;
            AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient _cloudWatchClient = new();
            _RegionEndPoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");
            AwsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("AWSAccessKey","AWSSecretAccessKey");
            _cloudWatchClient = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(AwsCredentials, _RegionEndPoint);                
            return _cloudWatchClient;
         });


What's your end goal here? What do you want to achieve?

No, you cannot change the AWS region dynamically at runtime for the same AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient instance. Once the client is instantiated with a specific region, it’s locked to that region.
Here's Why?
The AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient is region-specific, meaning each instance is tied to a single AWS region when created. AWS SDK clients don't support changing the region directly after initialization because it ensures consistency for API calls.
Solution
To handle multiple regions, you have a few options:

Create a new client per region as needed (on the fly) during the loop.
Use a transient client instead of a singleton — create a new instance within each request for each region.

Here’s how you can adjust your code:
services.AddSingleton(sp =>
{
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new("AWSAccessKey", "AWSSecretAccessKey");
    return awsCredentials;
});

public async Task MonitorLogGroups(IEnumerable<string> regions)
{
    var awsCredentials = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BasicAWSCredentials>();

    foreach (var region in regions)
    {
        var regionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region);
        using var cloudWatchClient = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(awsCredentials, regionEndpoint);

        // Fetch new log events from this region...
        await GetNewLogEvents(cloudWatchClient);
    }
}

With this approach, you only instantiate a client for each region when needed (within the loop), ensuring efficiency and simplicity. The DI container holds only the credentials, and each loop iteration creates the appropriate client for the target region.
